# Google Compute Engine - Click to Deploy

Tags: drupal, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use the Google Compute Engine's click to deploy feature to setup a new VM with Drupal installed.  Having chosen my basic setup and clicked the 'Deploy Drupal' button, I receive the following errors:

- "Unable to determine whether this software has been deployed. Reload the page to try again"
- "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page."

I've tried varying my settings such as the Zone to deploy to; waiting 24 hours before retrying and I've tried deploying a LAMP Stack instead, but all with the same results.

Is it likely that I have a setting \ permission wrong somewhere?  (I've checked that I am the project owner)
Or perhaps there is an issue with the feature at the moment?  It is a Beta feature after-all.

Many thanks in advance.

Lee

Comment: As an alternative, try using the [Bitnami Drupal launcher](https://bitnami.com/stack/drupal/cloud/google).

Comment: Thank you @misha-brukman - I'll try this if I cannot get the click-to-deploy option working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Click to Deploy with Google Compute Engine you need to make sure "Google Cloud Deployment Manager API" is enabled on your project. You can enable this API from Developer console->APIs page.

Moreover, if you have multiple accounts added in your browser try using Chrome Incognito tab to login in order to make sure your email has the right permissions.

Comment: It doesn't look like either of these issues are causing my problem.   The API is running - I've disabled and re-enabled just to be sure.  Trying the same thing in Incognito tab made no change either.  Thank you for the suggestions so far.

Comment: Scrap that - the API seems to have been where my problem lay after all.  I created a fresh project which didn't have the API enabled by default, so I enabled it and tried again which seems to have done the trick.  Hopefully this helps others too.  Thanks again @faizan